Google Cloud Run deployments failing after updating to .NET 9
I am deploying my Blazor Server app via Google Cloud Run. But it has been failing since I updated my project to .NET 9. Do I need to make any specific settings on gCloud? The error I am getting is
The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short.

Maybe I am misinterpreting this issue, but the app used to work on port 8080 and it is indeed exposed. What could it be?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
I am exposing the port like this in Program.cs -
var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "8080";
var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}";
app.Run(url);

And I have also set the port to 8080 in gCloud Run Service as well.
Edit - I am deploying directly from the source. The docker image is being created on the cloud itself when I run the "gcloud run deploy" command. Deployment region is us-west1.

Can you provide a [mcve] (ideally not a Blazor Server app, just an absolutely minimal web app - dotnet new web does a good job here. Please tell us exactly how you're deploying. I'm happy to look into this, but I need some more context.

@JonSkeet I did try creating a "Hello World" empty Blazor server app and tried deploying it on gcloud via cli - gcloud run deploy. But it does not seem to be working either.

A minimal API would be simpler than a Blazor app IMO - but please edit the question to provide details to make it trivial for anyone to reproduce the problem. (Which region are you deploying to? Are you just deploying from source, or using an image? Did you look at the build logs if you're deploying from source?)

I am happy to report that I have fixed my issue. Here's the solution in case someone faces the same issue -
I added these two in dockerfile
# Set environment variable for the listening port, as required by Cloud Run
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080

ENV PORT 8080

FYI - I already had EXPOSE 8080 and yet, the above two lines were required. This makes sense, as the error suggested something about PORT 8080. However, I still do not understand why these two lines were required as it was working fine before. I wonder if it is because of the dotnet 9 upgrade. Let me know if anyone has a clue.
Cheers!
